# Why won't debug linker file compile (ld:200 cannot move location counter backwards)

Tags: c, linker, embedded

Now before you you tell me my program is using too much memory...

I know what "cannot move location counter backwards means"...
here is the real problem...
 I have a linker file that WILL compile no problem.

call this linker file release version....

```
MEMORY
{
/* SOFTCONSOLE FLASH USE: microsemi-smartfusion2-envm */
rom (rx)  : ORIGIN = 0x20000000, LENGTH = 35k

/* SmartFusion2 internal eSRAM */
ram (rwx) : ORIGIN = 0x20008C00, LENGTH = 29k
}

RAM_START_ADDRESS   = 0x20008C00;           /* Must be the same value MEMORY region ram ORIGIN above. */
RAM_SIZE            = 29k;                  /* Must be the same value MEMORY region ram LENGTH above. */
MAIN_STACK_SIZE     = 11k;                  /* Cortex main stack size. */
MIN_SIZE_HEAP       = 512;                  /* needs to be calculated for your application */
```

notice the entire space occupied is 64k... this compiles
but when I try to use the following linker file (debug); I get the location counter error

```
MEMORY
{

/* SmartFusion2 internal eSRAM */
ram (rwx) : ORIGIN = 0x20000000, LENGTH = 64k
}

RAM_START_ADDRESS   = 0x20000000;       /* Must be the same value MEMORY region ram ORIGIN above. */
RAM_SIZE            = 64k;              /* Must be the same value MEMORY region ram LENGTH above. */
MAIN_STACK_SIZE     = 11k;               /* Cortex main stack size. */
MIN_SIZE_HEAP       = 512;              /* needs to be calculated for your application */
```

THE ONLY differences between the two linker files are show plus anywhere there is a >rom or >ram AT>rom directive in the release version, it is replace by >ram in the debug version...

I am using the same exact optimize and debugging flags
When I try to link the debug version i get the following error

```
ld:200 cannot move location counter backwards (from 20011d80 to 2000d400)
```

Anyone have any ideas???

Comment: I just solved the riddle, had to uncheck the -nodefaultlibs flags

Comment: We need to see the _complete_ linker scripts, both of them, to answer this question.  The problem is not in the code you showed us.  (I am fairly sure I know what the problem is, but I cannot properly explain it without a concrete chunk of script to point at.  It has nothing to do with `-nodefaultlibs` and I'm surprised that had any effect at all.)